# wordpress rest api response sending html content type issue with forward slash in URL

Tags: wordpress

From my custom Wordpress rest api, i need to return below text as content type html.

`OK
ImageSendURL=www.yourdomain.xxx/Plugin/DownloadOrders`

Here is my code to return the same

```
return new WP_REST_Response( "OK  \n  URL={$options['url']}", 200, array('content-type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8'));
```

But this returns

```
"OK  \n  URL=http:\/\/yourdomain.xxx\/Plugin\/DownloadOrders"
```

I don't want the leading and trailing double quotes " and also the URL is kind screwed up. how can i fix this?

with the below code:

```
echo "OK  \n  ImageSendURL={$options['url']}";
return new WP_REST_Response( "", 200, array('content-type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8'));
```

i got

`OK ImageSendURL=http://yourdomain.xxx/Plugin/DownloadOrders""`

now not sure how to get rid of the trailing ""

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the quotes are there because it's using the WP_HTTP_Response class that trying to give you a json as a response (uses the `json_encode()` function)

Don't do 'return', just do

```
header('Content-Type: text/html')
echo '<your html here>';
exit();
```

the exit function don't let the Wordpress to use WP_HTTP_Response class